# CLI Screenshot/Streaming screen

Tags: server, command-line, screen, screenshot

is there any way how i can make a screenshot of CLI command "screen -r", then save it as .txt? And set it up as cron job so i can stream my "screen -r" command? Is there any way how i can stream my "screen -r" command?

I know how to set up cronjob.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Screen has a hardcopy feature, which saves the contents of the current window to a hardcopy.* file in the current directory. By default it's bound to `Ctrl-A h`.